# owner of apartment complex with tenants inoperable or leaking vehicles

Tags: parking

I have a tenant in Memphis, Tn. who's vehicle is on 3 tires, the 4th no axle , up on a jack old me that he would have it up and running this past monday, today is friday. what can I do?

Comment: Is there anything in the lease about this situation? How about the city ordinances?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is in an off-street parking space that residents can use, either because they directly rent it from you, or as a perk for renting an apartment. In the future, you can include contract language that requires any parked vehicles to be operable and not leaking. Or, include a clean-up clause (in case of spills). You will have to decide how strict you want to be, given that new restrictions are likely to annoy existing tenants. There are many other options, which you should discuss with your lawyer.

In case you did not contractually grant the tenant an unfettered right to use the parking space, you may be able to tell him to move the car (or have it towed -- the legality of that depends on local law). A verbal agreement counts, so discuss this with your lawyer, who can advise you whether you have a contractual obligation to let the guy remain in his spot.